# BLE Custom Scan Response

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

Working with ESP32 and IDF

- I'm working in developing an application that advertises BLE data. I need to send custom data to each one of the different devices scanning. I'm able to write a custom manufacturer data. I  can also write a custom scan response message but, can a different custom response message be sent to each individual remote device? If possible, how do I do it?
- I have multiple iOS software for checking the BLE data but I have not been able to find one that displays both the Advertisement data and the scan response data in real-time. Does anyone know of one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't ask two completely separate questions in one question. But anyway:

The Bluetooth specification has no way of specifying different scan response data for different scan request bluetooth addresses. The address field in the scan request is there only to make it possible to discard scan requests from devices that are not in the white list.

The iOS api does not differentiate advertisement packets from scan response packets, so I don't think any app can do this. But you should however be able to get a notification as soon as some data arrives. I guess nRF Connect does this.